# Msbuild from command line does not output Csc warnings and output

Tags: msbuild

When I build my solution from the command line using **msbuild**, I don't get any output from the csharp compiler (Csc) like visual studio does.

For example, if I build my solution in Visual studio I get:

`warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected`

When I build from command line using msbuild, I get no warning at all (I want the warning to appear!)

Edit: the /verbosity flag does not do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are building the same configuration?  Typically Visual Studio will build your Debug configuration by default.  MsBuild on the other hand will default to build your Release configuration.  Make sure that you have the warning levels set to the same level for both configurations in your project settings.

Comment: It must have been too late for me last night. I tried again, and now I do get warnings and errors. Once the project is built, warnings are not shown again. I forgot to do a cleanup first. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need to provide an argument for output verbosity...

From [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx):

Displays this amount of information in the build log. Individual loggers display events based upon the verbosity level. A logger can also be configured to ignore the verbosity setting.

The available verbosity levels are q[uiet], m[inimal], n[ormal], d[etailed], and diag[nostic]. /v is also acceptable. For example:

/verbosity:quiet

Comment: I already tried that, unfortunately it still does not give any Csc output.